# how to identify nil intent using Intent Classification techniques

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

When we have to focus on only one domain (say weather) and we use a LSTM model to identify sub-intents inside weather using softmax classifier (which picks the sub-intent with highest score), what is the way to handle non-weather queries for which we want to say we don't have any answer? The problem is that there are too many outside domains and I don't know if it is feasible to generate data for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no really good way to do this.

In practice these are common approaches:

1. Build a class of examples of stuff you want to ignore. For a chatbot this might be greetings ("hello", "hi!", "how are you") or obscenities.
2. Create a confidence threshold and give an uncertain reply if  all intents are below the threshold.